# how to scrape this with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use simple html dom to extract elements from a file that looks like this.

- The file has several tables that look the same `class=sometable`.
- Each table has a few `<tr class=sometr>`.
- Then inside each tr, I have `th` that has the title, and a td that has a category.

What I want to extract is all titles `class=title` and their corresponding category number `class=category` for all table rows in all tables. I've loaded the file in `$html`. Can someone tell me what I'm supposed to find after that? I've tried even `$collection = $html->find('tr');` and did a vardump on the collection but got nothing, so it looks like I'm not selecting right.

```
<table class="sometable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sometr">
      <th><a class="title">Table 1 Title1</a></th>
      <td class="category" id="categ-113"></td>
      <td class="somename">Table 1 Title 1 name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>                           
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="sometable">
</table>

<table class="sometable">
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested [this](http://pastebin.com/kRuqLPCh) and it works

```
$tables = $dom->find('table[@class="sometable"]');

foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $titles = $table->find('a[@class="title"]');
    foreach($titles as $title)
    {
        echo "Link title = " . $title ."<br />";
    }

    $categories = $table->find('td[@class="category"]');
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        echo "Category id = " . $category->id ."<br />";
    }

    $titles2 = $table->find('td[@class="somename"]');
    foreach($titles2 as $title2)
    {
        echo "Title2 = " . $title2 ."<br />";
    }

}
```