# getting colspan from simple php dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)
>   [how to scrape this with Simple HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465907/how-to-scrape-this-with-simple-html-dom)

I have a table text like this:

```
$html='<table class="table1"><caption>Report</caption><tbody><tr> 
                    <th>#</th> 
                    <th>Date</th> 
                    <th>tablehead</th> 
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                        </tr><tr class="even"><td>10</td>
                        <td>2013-01-19</td> 
                        <td>somevalue</td> 
                        <td>500</td> 
                        <td>17</td> 
                        <td>8500</td> 
                        </tr><tr> 
                    <th colspan="4">&nbsp;</th> 
                    <th>402</th>
                    <th>196700</th> 
                </tr> </tbody></table>';
```

I want to know how can I get  the colspan value(when exists)? I am trying to use simple html dom but failed to get it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: like you get [any other element attribute with SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access)

Comment: Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead and search for attribute `@colspan`

Comment: @Havelock simplehtmldom does not support XPath

Comment: @Gordon I missed that bit :-/

Comment: @Gordon Sorry, I saw that but I did not notice that there is th instead of td in my text. That's why I could not get the colspan value. Additional question, can I anyhow replace all th into td including <th>, </th> or <th id="abc"... etc into <td>, </td> or <td id="abc"...

Comment: @user1416016 please do research before asking questions. You agreed to do so when you checked the checkbox at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. How to replace a node with SimpleHtmlDom has been asked and answered before.